# Newline in Constant Error and Syntax error, ',' expected

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am currently working through this tutorial- https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview

Everything is working except one page is filled with errors when I copy and paste it in there. This tutorial is done in Visual Studio 2013 and I am in 2015 but I didn't think that would make that big of difference, I made the assumption that the syntax would stay the same. Here is the code that when I paste in fills with 446 errors-

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    namespace WingtipToys.Models
    {
    public class ProductDatabaseInitializer :
    DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ProductContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ProductContext context)
        {
            GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));
            GetProducts().ForEach(p => context.Products.Add(p));
        }
        private static List<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            var categories = new List<Category> {
     new Category
     {
     CategoryID = 1,
    CategoryName = "Cars"
     },
    new Category
     {
     CategoryID = 2,
     CategoryName = "Planes"
     },
     new Category
     {
     CategoryID = 3,
     CategoryName = "Trucks"
     },
     new Category
     {
     CategoryID = 4,
    CategoryName = "Boats"
    },
     new Category
    {
     CategoryID = 5,
     CategoryName = "Rockets"
     },
     };
            return categories;
        }
        private static List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            var products = new List<Product> {
     new Product
     {
      ProductID = 1,
    ProductName = "Convertible Car",
    Description = "This convertible car is fast! The engine is
    powered by a neutrino based battery (not included)." +
    "Power it up and let it go!",
     ImagePath="carconvert.png",
    UnitPrice = 22.50,
    CategoryID = 1
     },
     new Product
     {
     ProductID = 2,
      ProductName = "Old-time Car",
     Description = "There's nothing old about this toy car,
    except it's looks. Compatible with other old toy cars.",
     ImagePath="carearly.png",
     UnitPrice = 15.95,
     CategoryID = 1
     },
     new Product
     {
     ProductID = 3,
    ProductName = "Fast Car",
    Description = "Yes this car is fast, but it also floats in
    water.",
     ImagePath="carfast.png",
    UnitPrice = 32.99,
    CategoryID = 1
     },
     new Product
     {
     ProductID = 4,
    ProductName = "Super Fast Car",
    Description = "Use this super fast car to entertain guests.
    Lights and doors work!",
    ImagePath="carfaster.png",
    UnitPrice = 8.95,
    CategoryID = 1
    },
     new Product
    {
 ProductID = 5,
ProductName = "Old Style Racer",
Description = "This old style racer can fly (with user
assistance). Gravity controls flight duration." +
        "No batteries required.",
 ImagePath = "carracer.png",
UnitPrice = 34.95,
CategoryID = 1
        },
 new Product
 {
 ProductID = 6,
ProductName = "Ace Plane",
Description = "Authentic airplane toy. Features realistic
color and details.",
 ImagePath="planeace.png",
UnitPrice = 95.00,
CategoryID = 2
 },
 new Product
 {
 ProductID = 7,
ProductName = "Glider",
Description = "This fun glider is made from real balsa
wood.Some assembly required.",
 ImagePath="planeglider.png",
UnitPrice = 4.95,
CategoryID = 2
 },
 new Product
 {
 ProductID = 8,
ProductName = "Paper Plane",
Description = "This paper plane is like no other paper
plane.Some folding required.",
 ImagePath="planepaper.png",
 UnitPrice = 2.95,
 CategoryID = 2
 },
 new Product
 {
 ProductID = 9,
ProductName = "Propeller Plane",
Description = "Rubber band powered plane features two
wheels.",
 ImagePath="planeprop.png",
UnitPrice = 32.95,
CategoryID = 2
 },
 new Product
 {
 ProductID = 10,
ProductName = "Early Truck",
Description = "This toy truck has a real gas powered
engine.Requires regular tune ups.",
 ImagePath= "truckearly.png",
UnitPrice = 15.00,
CategoryID = 3
 },
 new Product
 {
 ProductID = 11,
ProductName = "Fire Truck",
Description = "You will have endless fun with this one
quarter sized fire truck.",
 ImagePath= "truckfire.png",
UnitPrice = 26.00,
CategoryID = 3
 },
 new Product
 {
 ProductID = 12,
ProductName = "Big Truck",
Description = "This fun toy truck can be used to tow other
trucks that are not as big.",
 ImagePath="truckbig.png",
UnitPrice = 29.00,
CategoryID = 3
 },
 new Product
 {
 ProductID = 13,
ProductName = "Big Ship",
Description = "Is it a boat or a ship. Let this floating
vehicle decide by using its " +
 "artifically intelligent computer brain!",
 ImagePath="boatbig.png",
UnitPrice = 95.00,
CategoryID = 4
 },
 new Product
 {
 ProductID = 14,
ProductName = "Paper Boat",
Description = "Floating fun for all! This toy boat can be
assembled in seconds.Floats for minutes!" +
 "Some folding required.",
 ImagePath="boatpaper.png",
UnitPrice = 4.95,
CategoryID = 4
 },
 new Product
 {
 ProductID = 15,
ProductName = "Sail Boat",
Description = "Put this fun toy sail boat in the water and
let it go!",
 ImagePath="boatsail.png",
UnitPrice = 42.95,
CategoryID = 4
 },
 new Product
 {
 ProductID = 16,
ProductName = "Rocket",
Description = "This fun rocket will travel up to a height
of 200 feet.",
 ImagePath="rocket.png",
UnitPrice = 122.95,
CategoryID = 5
 }
 };
 return products;
 }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem while you copied the code as it split the description field into multiple lines, which is why you are seeing the error.

You could try like this and it will still allow multiple lines

```
  Description = @"This convertible car is fast! The engine is
    powered by a neutrino based battery (not included).
    Power it up and let it go!"
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else needs this. When pasting it in it put the description on two lines. If you put the description on one line it works fine.